# ADF Simple Unbounded Task Flow JSPX to JSPX call flow not working

Tags: oracle-adf, glassfish-4.1

I am using Eclipse [Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse 12.2.1.5](http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.2.1.5/neon/repository/) and I am using [Oracle ADF Essentials](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/index.html). I am trying to load another JSPX file on a button click `adfc-config.xml`

[image]

A.jspx

```
....
<af:outputText id="o1" value="Page A" inlineStyle="font-size: 36px"></af:outputText>
<af:button action="loadB" text="Load Page B" id="b1"></af:button>
....
```

B.jspx

```
....
<af:outputText id="o1" value="Page B" inlineStyle="font-size: 36px"></af:outputText>
....
```

When I execute `http://localhost:18080/taskflowsWeb/faces/A.jspx`

I get the output

[image]

But clicking on button nothing is happening

This means, only fragments (JSFF) will work? pages (JSPX) will not work?

Comment: Worked fine for me in JDev 12.2.1  Looks like you are using eclipse. Always include product, platform, version to help us help you.

Comment: Yes, I am using eclipse and ADF Essentials latest version. Are you trying to say that JSPX to JSPX action outcome will not work with ADF Essentials?

Answer (score 0):

just remove the first page extension from URL.